# How to identify sequences of price increasing for 5 times in a row?

Tags: r, dplyr, seq

I have a column of daily share prices for last 3 years. Now, I would like to find sequences where the price have increased 5 times in a row and then create a new column where I set " buy". Can anyone help me how to generate this?

That's what I tried but please sorry if that has not much sence because I'm a beginner

```
x <- FB[,"Close"] if (x<x+1, x+1<x+2, x+2<x+3, x+3<x+4, x+4<5) { FB$buy <- 1 }
```

Comment: can you please share with us the code you tried so far

Comment: x <- FB[,"Close"]
if (x<x+1,
    x+1<x+2,
    x+2<x+3,
    x+3<x+4,
    x+4<5) {
  
  FB$buy <- 1
}

That's what I tried but please sorry if that has not much sence because I'm a beginner

Comment: sorry I was not clear, it is best you edit your post and put the code there. Use code markdown for clarity, the edit window has the info on how to do that

Comment: I get this message when I want to edit it: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code." Thanks for your willingness to help but I need to give up :/

Comment: I edited your question, please take a look how I marked your code (reverse triple ticks) so you know what to do the next time around

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tag for this post said `dplyr` so I'll provide a `dplyr` method instead of a base `R` method. It's a brute force method but should be pretty easy to follow.

```
library(dplyr) 

FB <- data.frame(
  "Close" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Brute Force dplyr
x <- FB %>%
  mutate(buy = Close>lag(Close,1) & 
           lag(Close,1)>lag(Close,2) & 
           lag(Close,2)>lag(Close,3) & 
           lag(Close,3)>lag(Close,4) & 
           lag(Close,4)>lag(Close,5)
         ) %>%
  # If you really need a 1 instead of a True
  mutate(buy = as.numeric(buy)) # %>%
  # If there weren't 5 previous the result is NA
  # and you can impute something that makes sense
  # if anything makes sense.
  # mutate(buy = ifelse(is.na(buy),0,buy))
x
# Close buy
#     1  NA
#     2  NA
#     3  NA
#     4  NA
#     5  NA
#     6   1
#     1   0
#     2   0
#     3   0
#     4   0
#     1   0
#     2   0
#     3   0
#     4   0
#     5   0
#     6   1
```

Comment: Thank you very much Adam!! Kind regards from Switzerland